# Android getIntent().getExtra() returning null

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, serializable

I'm making a Bluetooth app, trying to pass an instance of BluetoothConnection class (which holds the inner classes ConnectThread and ConnectedThread) between activities. etIntgent() on BlindsActivity returns "BlindsActivity", not the actual parent intent. getParentActivityIntent() seems to work, but calling getParentActivityIntent().getExtra is always returning null, even for String data.

Code from DeviceListActivity: (the parent activity)

> public class DeviceListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Serializable{
>
> ```
> //widgets
> ListView devicesView;
>
> //Bluetooth
> private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;
> private BluetoothDevice btDevice;
> private Set<BluetoothDevice> setPairedDevices;
> private ArrayList arrayListPairedDevices;
> private BluetoothConnection btConnection;
> public boolean connected;
>
>
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>
>     //set view
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_bluetooth);
>
>     //call widgets
>     devicesView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewDeviceList);
>
>     //TEST
>     String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("TEST");
>
>     //check bluetooth is avaiable and on
>     btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
>     if (btAdapter == null) {
>         displayMessage("Device doesn't support bluetooth");
>         finish();
>     }
>     else if (!btAdapter.isEnabled()) {//if bluetooth is switched off request permission to turn on
>         Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
>         startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
>     }
>
>     //get all paired devices
>     arrayListPairedDevices = new ArrayList();
>     setPairedDevices = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();//Set of all paired devices
>     if (setPairedDevices.size() > 0) {
>         //if there are paired devices, get name and MAC address of each
>         for (BluetoothDevice dev : setPairedDevices){
>             arrayListPairedDevices.add(dev.getName() + "\n" + dev.getAddress());
>         }
>     } else if(!btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
>         displayMessage("Please enable Bluetooth before proceeding");
>         finish();
>     } else{
>         displayMessage("No paired devices\nPair with relevant device before proceeding");
>         finish();
>     }
>
>     //display bluetooth devices
>     final ArrayAdapter arrAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayListPairedDevices);
>     devicesView.setAdapter(arrAdapter);
>     devicesView.setOnItemClickListener(myListClickListener); //Method called when the device from the list is clicked
>
> }
>
> private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener myListClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {//make listView items clickable
>     public void onItemClick(AdapterView av, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {
>         //get the device MAC address, the last 17 chars in the View
>         String info = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
>         String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);
>         btDevice = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);//create new device with chosen address
>
>         //CONNECTION HAPPENS HERE
>
>         btConnection = new BluetoothConnection(btDevice);
>
>
>         if(btConnection.connect()){
>             //if connection success
>             Intent intent = new Intent(DeviceListActivity.this, BlindsActivity.class);
>             intent.putExtra("TEST", "test");
>             intent.putExtra("CONNECTION", (Serializable) btConnection);
>
>             startActivity(intent);
>         }
>         else{
>             displayMessage("Error connecting - please try again");
>         }
>     }
> };
>
>
> private void displayMessage(String s) {
>     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
> }
> ```

Relevant code snippet from BlindsActivity: (the child/recieving activity)
NOTE getParentActivityIntent() is returning the correct intent here, but getIntent() is not.

BluetoothConnection btConnection and String s are both null

```
public class BlindsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  Serializable {

    //widgets
    private Button btnProgram, btnOpen, btnClose, btn34Open, btn34Close, btnCustom, btnSetup, btnSubmit, btnDisconnect;
    private TextView txtViewConnected;

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //set view
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_blinds);

        //call widgets
        btnProgram = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnProgram);
        btnOpen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOpen);
        btnClose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClose);
        btn34Open = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn34Open);
        btn34Close = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn34Closed);
        btnCustom = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCustom);
        btnSetup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSetUp);
        btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
        btnDisconnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDisconnect);

        //set action bar title
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("Blinds");


        //receive instance of BluetoothConnection from previous activity
        Intent i = getParentActivityIntent();
        String s = i.getStringExtra("TEST");
        BluetoothConnection btConnection = (BluetoothConnection) i.getSerializableExtra("CONNECTION");

        //get instance of ConnectedThread from BluetoothActivity
        final BluetoothConnection.ConnectedThread connectedThread = btConnection.connectedThread;
```

BluetoothConnection class:

```
public class BluetoothConnection implements Serializable {



    //Bluetooth
    private BluetoothDevice btDevice;
    public ConnectThread connectThread;
    public ConnectedThread connectedThread;
    private boolean connected;
    private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

    public BluetoothConnection (BluetoothDevice device){
        //constructor
        btDevice = device;
    }

    public boolean connect(){
        //initialises ConnectThread - done here for syncing with UI Thread and passing between activities
         connectThread = new ConnectThread(btDevice);
         connectThread.start();

         try{
             // sync threads to return only after the connection is created
             connectThread.join();
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

         return connected;
    }



    @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    Handler handler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg){
            byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            int begin = (int)msg.arg1;
            int end = (int)msg.arg2;

            switch(msg.what){
                case 1:
                    String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);
                    writeMessage = writeMessage.substring(begin, end);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };



    public class ConnectThread extends Thread implements Serializable{

        public final BluetoothSocket btSocket;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice btDevice){
            //constructor

            BluetoothSocket tmpSocket = null;
            try {//attempts to obtain and open a Bluetooth Socket, uses temp socket until confirmed working
                tmpSocket = btDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
            } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

            btSocket = tmpSocket;
        }

        public void run(){
            //attempts to connect socket to remote device
            try{
                btSocket.connect();
                connected = true;
            } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace(); connected = false; return;}

            connectedThread = new ConnectedThread(btSocket);
            connectedThread.start();
        }

        public boolean disconnect(){
            try {
                btSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace(); return false;}
            return true;
        }
    }//end class ConnectThread


    public class ConnectedThread extends Thread implements Serializable{

        private final InputStream inStream;
        private final OutputStream outStream;
        private final BluetoothSocket btSocket;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket){
            //constructor

            btSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            try{ //attempts to open input and output streams on socket
                tmpIn = btSocket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = btSocket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

            inStream = tmpIn;
            outStream = tmpOut;

        }

        public void run(){
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int begin = 0;
            int bytes = 0;

            while (true){
                try{
                    bytes += inStream.read(buffer, bytes, buffer.length - bytes);
                    for (int i = begin; i < bytes; i++){
                        if (buffer[i] == "#".getBytes()[0]){
                            handler.obtainMessage(1, begin, i, buffer).sendToTarget();
                            begin = i+1;
                            if(i == (bytes - 1)){
                                bytes = begin = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace(); break;}
            }

        }

        public void write(byte[] bytes){
            try{
                outStream.write(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }

        public void cancel(){
            try{
                btSocket.close();
            } catch(IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }


    }
}//END
```

And here is my AndroidManifest.xml

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
>
> <application
>     android:allowBackup="true"
>     android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
>     android:label="@string/app_name"
>     android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
>     android:supportsRtl="true"
>     android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
>     <activity
>         android:name=".MainActivity"
>         android:configChanges="orientation"
>         android:label="@string/app_name"
>         android:screenOrientation="portrait"
>         android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
>     <activity
>         android:name=".DeviceListActivity"
>         android:configChanges="orientation"
>         android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
>         android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
>     <activity
>         android:name=".BlindsActivity"
>         android:configChanges="orientation"
>         android:parentActivityName=".DeviceListActivity"
>         android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
>     <activity
>         android:name=".ProgramActivity"
>         android:configChanges="orientation"
>         android:parentActivityName=".BlindsActivity"
>         android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
>     <activity android:name=".SetUpActivity" />
> </application>
> ```

Comment: How are you declaring `DeviceListActivity` in `AndroidMenifest.xml` ?

Comment: Updated original post to include Manifest!

Comment: `getParentActivityIntent()` is not what you seem to think it is. You do want `getIntent()`, which is the `Intent` that started the current `Activity`, and should have your extras on it.